# Getting the user's Documents folder in Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0

I want to use a PowerShell script to automate tasks related to the user when the user logs in.

Sometimes a user will have moved his Documents folder from the default location.  How can I determine the location of the user's Documents folder in PowerShell?

Comment: Your latest revision changed the question too much.  The question you originally asked has been answered, please post a *new* question about looking up folder paths from a GUID.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

try this:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
```

When supplying it to a command, make sure to place it into parentheses:

```
cd ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))
```

Comment: Hello, it works for some folders but not all, for example, i cannot retrieve system's "Saved Games" folder with this (or i'm not doing it correctly)

Comment: Created another question about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049875/getting-any-special-folder-path-in-powershell-using-folder-guid

Comment: This does not work:`Set-Location [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")` `Set-Location : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "MyDocuments" akzeptiert.` However, if I create a variable as Deeps does, it works..

Comment: @Timo You need to add parentheses around the second function call: `Set-Location ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments"))`.
You can't just do `Do-Something -Path Get-Something -Param`, but `Do-Something -Path (Get-Something -Param)` works.

Answer (score 20):

To get a list of known folder names use the following command:

```
[enum]::GetNames( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder] )
```

To get a list of names and paths:

```
[enum]::GetNames( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder] ) | 
    Select @{ n="Name"; e={$_}},
        @{ n="Path"; e={ [environment]::getfolderpath( $_ ) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$mydocuments = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")
```

Comment: Hello, it works for some folders but not all, for example, i cannot retrieve system's "Saved Games" folder with this (or i'm not doing it correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other answers but allows use of Intellisense in IDE to view/confirm the names of all the predefined SpecialFolder enum options

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::MyDocuments)
```