# Getting any special folder path in Powershell using folder GUID

Tags: powershell, pinvoke, powershell-3.0

I want to use a PowerShell script to automate tasks related to the user when the user logs in.

Sometimes a user will have moved his Documents folder from the default location.  How can I determine the location of the user's Documents folder in PowerShell with a method that will work for all special folders?

I tried to use SHGetKnownFolderPath calls from PowerShell based on [Lee Holmes work](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough)

As pinvoke website C# sample doesn't use StringBuilder, I assumed it was not required and stripped builder + "-Using" references

```powershell
param($KNOWNFOLDERID)

$Pinvoke = @’
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid,
     uint dwFlags,
     IntPtr hToken,
     out String pszPath  // API uses CoTaskMemAlloc
     );
‘@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Pinvoke  
    -Name Win32Utils -Namespace SHGetKnownFolderPath  
    -PassThru

$type::SHGetKnownFolderPath($KNOWNFOLDERID)
```

I also tried to use New-PInvoke from [here](http://poshcode.org/1409) 
with "shell32.dll" as lib value and

```powershell
int SHGetKnownFolderPath(     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid,     uint dwFlags,     IntPtr hToken,     out String pszPath  )
```

as signature value, then using from powershell

```powershell
SHGetKnownFolderPath FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7 0 0 [ref]$path
```

I ends with this error

```
Argument: '4' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
At line:1 char:56
+ New-Item Function:Global:SHGetKnownFolderPath -Value { [Microsoft.PowerShell.Com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonRefArgumentToRefParameterMsg
```

I don't understand where I got wrong on both trials.

**SOLUTION:**
Windows7Library binary found by Kayasax on codeplex works for lazy people like me, or David Heffernan 's scriptlet that allow more customization, but may need some handwork if you use custom special folders, but more customizable, both answers are valid !

Comment: Please note solutions using CSIDL are prohibed as they are not able to get *ANY* special folder, CSIDL is outdated, as per Microsoft official website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Users are able to change special folders location themselves, including documents, saved games and thinking the folder will be inside user profile path will lead to problems later if I run the script on a machine not using default value. I cannot use any solutions that assume the folder is on the default path, but that would not be a problem as GUID solutions will give the folder's full path.

Comment: So this is for Vista and later right?

Comment: It's for system that can run Powershell V3 as the question was flagged with it, including Windows 7/Windows Server 2008R2 and above. I don't know if it's possible to install Powershell V3 on Vista.

Comment: My point being that you understand that XP is out of the question if you want known folder IDs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to wrap up the low-level p/invoke in C# code than it is to attempt to call it directly from PowerShell. Here I've taken the pinvoke.net declarations and wrapped them up in a simple method that accepts a known folder GUID and returns the path.

```
Add-Type @"

    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public static class KnownFolder
    {
        public static readonly Guid AddNewPrograms = new Guid( "de61d971-5ebc-4f02-a3a9-6c82895e5c04" );
        public static readonly Guid AdminTools = new Guid( "724EF170-A42D-4FEF-9F26-B60E846FBA4F" );
        public static readonly Guid AppUpdates = new Guid( "a305ce99-f527-492b-8b1a-7e76fa98d6e4" );
        public static readonly Guid CDBurning = new Guid( "9E52AB10-F80D-49DF-ACB8-4330F5687855" );
        public static readonly Guid ChangeRemovePrograms = new Guid( "df7266ac-9274-4867-8d55-3bd661de872d" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonAdminTools = new Guid( "D0384E7D-BAC3-4797-8F14-CBA229B392B5" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonOEMLinks = new Guid( "C1BAE2D0-10DF-4334-BEDD-7AA20B227A9D" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonPrograms = new Guid( "0139D44E-6AFE-49F2-8690-3DAFCAE6FFB8" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonStartMenu = new Guid( "A4115719-D62E-491D-AA7C-E74B8BE3B067" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonStartup = new Guid( "82A5EA35-D9CD-47C5-9629-E15D2F714E6E" );
        public static readonly Guid CommonTemplates = new Guid( "B94237E7-57AC-4347-9151-B08C6C32D1F7" );
        public static readonly Guid ComputerFolder = new Guid( "0AC0837C-BBF8-452A-850D-79D08E667CA7" );
        public static readonly Guid ConflictFolder = new Guid( "4bfefb45-347d-4006-a5be-ac0cb0567192" );
        public static readonly Guid ConnectionsFolder = new Guid( "6F0CD92B-2E97-45D1-88FF-B0D186B8DEDD" );
        public static readonly Guid Contacts = new Guid( "56784854-C6CB-462b-8169-88E350ACB882" );
        public static readonly Guid ControlPanelFolder = new Guid( "82A74AEB-AEB4-465C-A014-D097EE346D63" );
        public static readonly Guid Cookies = new Guid( "2B0F765D-C0E9-4171-908E-08A611B84FF6" );
        public static readonly Guid Desktop = new Guid( "B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641" );
        public static readonly Guid Documents = new Guid( "FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7" );
        public static readonly Guid Downloads = new Guid( "374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B" );
        public static readonly Guid Favorites = new Guid( "1777F761-68AD-4D8A-87BD-30B759FA33DD" );
        public static readonly Guid Fonts = new Guid( "FD228CB7-AE11-4AE3-864C-16F3910AB8FE" );
        public static readonly Guid Games = new Guid( "CAC52C1A-B53D-4edc-92D7-6B2E8AC19434" );
        public static readonly Guid GameTasks = new Guid( "054FAE61-4DD8-4787-80B6-090220C4B700" );
        public static readonly Guid History = new Guid( "D9DC8A3B-B784-432E-A781-5A1130A75963" );
        public static readonly Guid InternetCache = new Guid( "352481E8-33BE-4251-BA85-6007CAEDCF9D" );
        public static readonly Guid InternetFolder = new Guid( "4D9F7874-4E0C-4904-967B-40B0D20C3E4B" );
        public static readonly Guid Links = new Guid( "bfb9d5e0-c6a9-404c-b2b2-ae6db6af4968" );
        public static readonly Guid LocalAppData = new Guid( "F1B32785-6FBA-4FCF-9D55-7B8E7F157091" );
        public static readonly Guid LocalAppDataLow = new Guid( "A520A1A4-1780-4FF6-BD18-167343C5AF16" );
        public static readonly Guid LocalizedResourcesDir = new Guid( "2A00375E-224C-49DE-B8D1-440DF7EF3DDC" );
        public static readonly Guid Music = new Guid( "4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43" );
        public static readonly Guid NetHood = new Guid( "C5ABBF53-E17F-4121-8900-86626FC2C973" );
        public static readonly Guid NetworkFolder = new Guid( "D20BEEC4-5CA8-4905-AE3B-BF251EA09B53" );
        public static readonly Guid OriginalImages = new Guid( "2C36C0AA-5812-4b87-BFD0-4CD0DFB19B39" );
        public static readonly Guid PhotoAlbums = new Guid( "69D2CF90-FC33-4FB7-9A0C-EBB0F0FCB43C" );
        public static readonly Guid Pictures = new Guid( "33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB" );
        public static readonly Guid Playlists = new Guid( "DE92C1C7-837F-4F69-A3BB-86E631204A23" );
        public static readonly Guid PrintersFolder = new Guid( "76FC4E2D-D6AD-4519-A663-37BD56068185" );
        public static readonly Guid PrintHood = new Guid( "9274BD8D-CFD1-41C3-B35E-B13F55A758F4" );
        public static readonly Guid Profile = new Guid( "5E6C858F-0E22-4760-9AFE-EA3317B67173" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramData = new Guid( "62AB5D82-FDC1-4DC3-A9DD-070D1D495D97" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFiles = new Guid( "905e63b6-c1bf-494e-b29c-65b732d3d21a" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFilesX64 = new Guid( "6D809377-6AF0-444b-8957-A3773F02200E" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFilesX86 = new Guid( "7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFilesCommon = new Guid( "F7F1ED05-9F6D-47A2-AAAE-29D317C6F066" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFilesCommonX64 = new Guid( "6365D5A7-0F0D-45E5-87F6-0DA56B6A4F7D" );
        public static readonly Guid ProgramFilesCommonX86 = new Guid( "DE974D24-D9C6-4D3E-BF91-F4455120B917" );
        public static readonly Guid Programs = new Guid( "A77F5D77-2E2B-44C3-A6A2-ABA601054A51" );
        public static readonly Guid Public = new Guid( "DFDF76A2-C82A-4D63-906A-5644AC457385" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicDesktop = new Guid( "C4AA340D-F20F-4863-AFEF-F87EF2E6BA25" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicDocuments = new Guid( "ED4824AF-DCE4-45A8-81E2-FC7965083634" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicDownloads = new Guid( "3D644C9B-1FB8-4f30-9B45-F670235F79C0" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicGameTasks = new Guid( "DEBF2536-E1A8-4c59-B6A2-414586476AEA" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicMusic = new Guid( "3214FAB5-9757-4298-BB61-92A9DEAA44FF" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicPictures = new Guid( "B6EBFB86-6907-413C-9AF7-4FC2ABF07CC5" );
        public static readonly Guid PublicVideos = new Guid( "2400183A-6185-49FB-A2D8-4A392A602BA3" );
        public static readonly Guid QuickLaunch = new Guid( "52a4f021-7b75-48a9-9f6b-4b87a210bc8f" );
        public static readonly Guid Recent = new Guid( "AE50C081-EBD2-438A-8655-8A092E34987A" );
        public static readonly Guid RecycleBinFolder = new Guid( "B7534046-3ECB-4C18-BE4E-64CD4CB7D6AC" );
        public static readonly Guid ResourceDir = new Guid( "8AD10C31-2ADB-4296-A8F7-E4701232C972" );
        public static readonly Guid RoamingAppData = new Guid( "3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D" );
        public static readonly Guid SampleMusic = new Guid( "B250C668-F57D-4EE1-A63C-290EE7D1AA1F" );
        public static readonly Guid SamplePictures = new Guid( "C4900540-2379-4C75-844B-64E6FAF8716B" );
        public static readonly Guid SamplePlaylists = new Guid( "15CA69B3-30EE-49C1-ACE1-6B5EC372AFB5" );
        public static readonly Guid SampleVideos = new Guid( "859EAD94-2E85-48AD-A71A-0969CB56A6CD" );
        public static readonly Guid SavedGames = new Guid( "4C5C32FF-BB9D-43b0-B5B4-2D72E54EAAA4" );
        public static readonly Guid SavedSearches = new Guid( "7d1d3a04-debb-4115-95cf-2f29da2920da" );
        public static readonly Guid SEARCH_CSC = new Guid( "ee32e446-31ca-4aba-814f-a5ebd2fd6d5e" );
        public static readonly Guid SEARCH_MAPI = new Guid( "98ec0e18-2098-4d44-8644-66979315a281" );
        public static readonly Guid SearchHome = new Guid( "190337d1-b8ca-4121-a639-6d472d16972a" );
        public static readonly Guid SendTo = new Guid( "8983036C-27C0-404B-8F08-102D10DCFD74" );
        public static readonly Guid SidebarDefaultParts = new Guid( "7B396E54-9EC5-4300-BE0A-2482EBAE1A26" );
        public static readonly Guid SidebarParts = new Guid( "A75D362E-50FC-4fb7-AC2C-A8BEAA314493" );
        public static readonly Guid StartMenu = new Guid( "625B53C3-AB48-4EC1-BA1F-A1EF4146FC19" );
        public static readonly Guid Startup = new Guid( "B97D20BB-F46A-4C97-BA10-5E3608430854" );
        public static readonly Guid SyncManagerFolder = new Guid( "43668BF8-C14E-49B2-97C9-747784D784B7" );
        public static readonly Guid SyncResultsFolder = new Guid( "289a9a43-be44-4057-a41b-587a76d7e7f9" );
        public static readonly Guid SyncSetupFolder = new Guid( "0F214138-B1D3-4a90-BBA9-27CBC0C5389A" );
        public static readonly Guid System = new Guid( "1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7" );
        public static readonly Guid SystemX86 = new Guid( "D65231B0-B2F1-4857-A4CE-A8E7C6EA7D27" );
        public static readonly Guid Templates = new Guid( "A63293E8-664E-48DB-A079-DF759E0509F7" );
        public static readonly Guid TreeProperties = new Guid( "5b3749ad-b49f-49c1-83eb-15370fbd4882" );
        public static readonly Guid UserProfiles = new Guid( "0762D272-C50A-4BB0-A382-697DCD729B80" );
        public static readonly Guid UsersFiles = new Guid( "f3ce0f7c-4901-4acc-8648-d5d44b04ef8f" );
        public static readonly Guid Videos = new Guid( "18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC" );
        public static readonly Guid Windows = new Guid( "F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23" );
    }

    public class shell32
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        private static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(
             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] 
             Guid rfid,
             uint dwFlags,
             IntPtr hToken,
             out IntPtr pszPath
         );

         public static string GetKnownFolderPath(Guid rfid)
         {
            IntPtr pszPath;
            if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(rfid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pszPath) != 0)
                return ""; // add whatever error handling you fancy
            string path = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pszPath);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pszPath);
            return path;
         }
    }

"@
```

**Example usage**

```
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> .\SHGetKnownFolderPath.ps1
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> [shell32]::GetKnownFolderPath([KnownFolder]::Documents)
C:\Users\username\Documents
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> [shell32]::GetKnownFolderPath([KnownFolder]::Downloads)
C:\Users\username\Downloads
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop> [shell32]::GetKnownFolderPath([KnownFolder]::InternetCache)
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

I know pretty much nothing about PowerShell, so I am confident that an experienced user will be able to wrap this up in a more idomatic PowerShell manner. However, I'm sure that the basic concept of handling the somewhat gnarly p/invoke inside the C# code, and presenting a higher-level interface to the PowerShell consumer is the right way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Hello, while it would work with GUID in the list, how would it work with future special folders that may be added by Microsoft ? It would require script updating, same for custom special folders a system may have, am i correct ? Will test what you are giving me anyway as it would be better than nothing in case i don't have find a solution that would require less maintenance.

Comment: You can pass any GUID that you like. The ones declared here are for your convenience. This shows you how to call the function that is in your question. It is the way to obtain paths from known folder guids.

Comment: Hard choices happens.

Comment: Note that the `InfoTip` value for the `Recent` folder in the Registry is known to have the corrupt `REG_SZ` value **`@shell32,dll,-12692`**. Notice that the file extension is separated with a **comma**, and actually, `InfoTip` keys are usually `REG_EXPAND_SZ`.  If you want to correct your registry, [here's](https://pastebin.com/WVFccLb3) the fix.

Answer (score 2):

you can list all the special folders with this command :

```
[enum]::GetNames([System.Environment+SpecialFolder])
```

If you want to get a physical path use this :

```
[environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use it with "Saved Games" folder , please? I have trouble finding it on the list.

Comment: i dont think saved games is a special folder. Usualy it's located under userprofile dir ( `$env:userprofile` )

Comment: It is as per Microsoft official documentation, that's why I asked how to do it by GUID as I knew I would get this answer that doesn't work with special folders created by Microsoft after the now unsupported XP.

Comment: i've found a module here that seems to do what you want : http://windowslibrariespsh.codeplex.com/releases/view/32315 you can use it like `Get-KnownFolder -KnownFolder "SavedGames" `

Comment: I will test it as soon as I get a Windows on hands, from reading the documentation it's likely I will keep this solution, please make a separate answer for this solution to allow me to flag it as answer after testing s.

Answer (score 1):

i've found a module here that seems to do what you want : windowslibrariespsh.codeplex.com/releases/view/32315 you can use it like this `Get-KnownFolder -KnownFolder "SavedGames"`

Comment: Hello, this solution doesn't work on x64 systems, i opened an issue on codeplex, required libs are x86 it seems :|

Comment: Managed to run it, don't know what was wrong. Your solution works for me, but we are on a code website and i think it's better to accept as answer code over binary. Hard choice.

Answer (score 0):

if user have moved his Document folder path you'll not be able to get it's location because after moving it to some other location it'll be treated as normal folder not system folder. however if you want the whole list of system folders you can try as @Kayasax suggested.

```
[enum]::GetNames([System.Environment+SpecialFolder])  //for whole list

$document = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")  //for MyDocument specifically
```

you can use other system folder name too at the place of "mydocuments".